# how to backup of specific tables from database sql server and save .bak file in computer using vb.net code

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, backup, smo

I want to backup some specific data of SQL database by using vb.net code. In fact i want to save this file as .BAK file and then i want to restore it.

I couldn't find anything. all the solutions in the web was about full backup of database and there was not any method to backup some tables via code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server does not permit backing up a single table. Full stop. No provision is made for this whatsoever.

It does permit *restoring* a single table from a complete backup, but this does not seem to be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to backup full database, but i can choose specific rows of some tables to add to this backup. you know my mean is that i will get full backup but i want choose which data of our tables add to this backup.

Comment: No. A backup is a complete copy of a database, to be used for bringing the database back from the dead at a future time.  What you seem to want is to **export** part of the database. You'll want to look into SSIS, which you can try out just by right-clicking the database in the navigation tree in SSMS, and choosing Tasks > Export Data.